# Entity framework fluent api mapping child to parent with foreign key that is not parent's ID

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I would like to map the child class but the foreign key on the child object is not the ID on the `Program` class. How can I use EF fluent API to define this relationship? Below are my classes.

```
public class Program
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProgramNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string ProgramNumber { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ProgramMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Program>
    {
        public ProgramMapping()
        {
            ToTable("PROGRAMS");

            HasKey(t => t.Id);

            Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
            Property(t => t.ProgramNumber).HasColumnName("PROGRAM_NUMBER");
        }
    }

    internal class ChildMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
    {
        public ChildMapping()
        {
            ToTable("CHILDREN");

            HasKey(t => t.Id);

            Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
            Property(t => t.ProgramNumber).HasColumnName("PROGRAM_NUMBER");
        }
    }
```

Comment: No can do in EF6. Looks like it might be possible in core: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support